# Can I redirect to home in blade view?

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-blade

I would like to redirect user (when he is not connected) in home page when he try to access a page in different langage than this localisation.

My router is made on a foreach function like this :

```
foreach(['es', 'fr', 'en'] as $lang)
```

and my view is create like this :

```
Route::view($param . __('education'), 'area.education')->name(areaEducation);
```

where $param is :

```
$param = $lang === 'fr' ? '/' : '/' . $lang . '/';
```

So I can't make a if condition directly in the routeur like this :

```
if($lang == 'es')
   Route::view($param . __('education'), 'area.education')->name(areaEducation);
else
   redirect('/');
```

because that's return an error because he don't find the route in other languages. (logic)

Also I can't do directly a return statement in my blade template like this :

```
@if(App::isLocale('es')
   @php(redirect('/')
@else
   "do stuff"
@endif
```

If someone have an idea...

Thanks a lot

EDIT

Finally, I decided to redirect the user like this :

```
Route::redirect('/education', '/');
Route::redirect('/en/education', '/');
```

at the end of the router files...

I don't think if its the right way to do that but...

Comment: Use middleware for such tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a middleware, that checks if the requested language is in your available languages array, if true, the middleware continues to the next request else it redirects to the homepage.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CheckLocale{

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next) {
        
        $availableLanguages = ['es', 'fr', 'en'];
        $currentLanguage = $request->route('language'); 
            
            if(in_array($currentLanguage, $availableLanguages))
                return $next($request);
        
        return redirect('/');

    }
```

Comment: cool, thanks a lot !